# Breeze: Metadata .isEmpty() not working as expected

Tags: breeze

I have the following method:

```
function _getById(entityName, id, navigationProperty) {
        var self = this;
        var manager = self.manager;

        if (manager.metadataStore.isEmpty()) {
            return manager.fetchMetadata().then(function () {
                var entityType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(entityName);
                var entityKey = new EntityKey(entityType, id);

                return EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(entityKey)
                    .expand(navigationProperty)
                    .using(manager)
                    .execute()
                    .to$q(querySucceeded);
            });
        }
        else {
            var entityType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(entityName);
            var entityKey = new EntityKey(entityType, id);

            return EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(entityKey)
                .expand(navigationProperty)
                .using(manager)
                .execute()
                .to$q(querySucceeded);
        }

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            return data;
        }
    }
```

This works fine if I navigate to the page through the application, however, if I load that page directly, I get the following error:

```
Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: 'Customer'. Be sure to execute a query 
or call fetchMetadata first.
```

Stepping through the code, it seems to go to the `else` part of my `if` statement, implying that the metadata store isn't empty, but from the error, it appears that it is? What have I done wrong here?

### Edit

I've made some changes but am still getting the same result:

```
    function _getById(entityName, id) {
        var self = this;
        var manager = self.manager;
        if (!manager.metadataStore.hasMetadataFor('breeze/ax')) {
            return manager.fetchMetadata()
               .then(_getEntityById(manager, entityName, id));
        }
        else {
            return $q.when(_getEntityById(manager, entityName, id));
        }
    }

    function _getEntityById(manager, entityName) {
        var entityType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(entityName);
        var entityKey = new EntityKey(entityType, id);

        return EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(entityKey)
            .using(manager)
            .execute()
            .to$q(querySucceeded);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            var entity = data.results[0];
            return entity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the two scenarios, but take a look inside your metadataStore just before the failure, it obviously has something in it.

Comment: The first scenario is to load the metadata if it is empty as `manager.metadataStore.getEntityType` requires the metadata to be loaded prior to being used. So I'm firstly checking if the metadataStore is empty, if it is then I fetch it..

Comment: No need to do that the FetchMetadata call does this internally. If  it has ever requested metadata for a specific dataservice it avoids making another trip to server and just returns the cached metadata.

Comment: If I load a page directly that calls `.getEntityType` then it throws the error that metadata isnt loaded, so I wrap it with the `fetchMetadata` if it is empty, otherwise I wrap it with a promise.

Comment: I would just always call "fetchMetadata", it will resolve immediately if the metadata has already been fetched. Note you can also call 'getEntityType with a 2nd parameter of true to suppress the exception i.e. 'getEntityType(typeName, true)'.  See http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html#method_getEntityType

Comment: If you call `fetchMetadata` when the metadata isn't empty it will throw an error saying that its already been loaded

Comment: You are right, Sorry.  In which case you should use the *MetadataStore.hasMetadataFor* method. See http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html#method_hasMetadataFor

Comment: @JayTraband I've tried `hasMetadataFor` and I still get the same result. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this before. The problem is; that when you load the page directly, it gets loaded before the call to fetching metadata is finished..(I assume your using `DurandalJS`)

What I did, is calling the method `fetchMetadata()` in the shell view, right before activating the router
so in your activate method in the shell view your code may look something like this:

```
  function activate() {

            return manager.fetchMetadata()
                 .then(boot)
                 .fail(failedInitialization);
        }

 function boot() {
            return router.map(routes)   // routes is our array of routes  
                .buildNavigationModel() 
                .activate();
        }
```

In this case, you won't have to check for the status of metadata since it will get called before loading the application and `MetadataStore.hasMetadataFor` will always return false.

Comment: I am actually using Angular and specifically, HotTowel.Angular.Breeze nuget package